# Is there a way to make it easier to attach images to `Markdown` in `Jekyll`?

Tags: image, markdown, jekyll

Recently, I am making a blog using `Jekyll`.
When creating a blog using Jekyll, the image file should be in `asset / images /`, It is quite inconvenient to specify the path to every image attachment code every time I create a markdown file like below

```
![img](/assets/images/aa.png')
```

Is there a way to make it easier to attach images to `Markdown` in `Jekyll`?

For example, set the image file path in front matter, or declaring an image path in `_config.yml`?

always thanks for your help. thnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a path in your `_config.yml`, for instance:

```
images: assets/images
```

In your post, page or document simply call this path with a

```
{{ site.images }}
```

and you are done!

Comment: thanks for your help, and I specify the image path in `_config.yml`. And I have a one more question, if I have two image folder? first case is image folder for markdown, second case is image folder for image mdae by python code. I don't wanna them mixed. Are there any way to solve it.

Comment: You should have a look at the jekyll documentation on [defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/). Maybe you can work with different scopes.   Otherwise you could always declare as many variables in `_config.yml` as you want. You even could use [data-files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) to point to your different asset directories.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rewrite rule (in .htaccess)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).(jpg|png|gif)l$ /assets/images/$1.$2
```

Now you can write

```
![img](aa.pngl)
```

The trailing `l` (like local) is mostly to avoid a redirect loop.
You could also add a shorter "directory" like `![img](l/aa.png)`

On another domain, you can catch direct on png, jpg etc.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpg$ https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/$1.jpg
```

and hotlink images

```
![](thumb/3/30/Jubilee_and_Munin%2C_Ravens%2C_Tower_of_London_2016-04-30.jpg/240px-Jubilee_and_Munin%2C_Ravens%2C_Tower_of_London_2016-04-30.jpg)
```

But be careful: all images will be redirected.

I have never used this in production, but it worked for me in testing.